# Why would IntelliJ IDEA not be able to index files for a GitHub commit?

Tags: github, intellij-idea, intellij-14

The title pretty much says it all, but to make things worse, new files aren't tracked as well. I figured that this is likely a rare exception, but it would be good to know what is causing the issue - in case a large project gets bugged by it. This question might help anyone who gets in this mess, so please post your suggestions.

Here is a screenshot of the situation: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMn3O.png

---

Here is the screenshot I posted of the `Settings... > Version Control > Ignored Files` page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9F0sq.png It shows what is wrong on the *3rd* line.

**If you still can't index:**
It might be because after removing the ignoring of your files, that the VCS hasn't been brought up to speed of the fact. Go to `VCS > Show Changes View` and then hit `CTRL+F5` or click the Refresh Icon. Now you have Unversioned Files and you're ready to add files to the index.

I have solved the issue with a roundabout way. What I did was: I didn't include the `.classpath` file that Eclipse creates. IntellIJ asked if I wanted to open `.project`, I canceled that and just opened the project regularly, that solved it for me. It might have quietly induced the ignore entry from the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjyeK.png).

Comment: This file is ignored. To understand why, please show the contents of your .gitignore file, as well as Settings | Version Control | Ignored Files.

Comment: yes, the third entry @Byrk is the culprit. you are ignoring your entire project folder

Comment: @Byrk Add that screenshot to your post

Comment: That's hilarious, I looked for anything that my have ignored the project, but didn't notice it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file is ignored. You have added your entire project directory to "Ignored files" in Settings | Version Control | Ignored Files, which leads to IntelliJ IDEA not showing any files as unversioned, and not allowing you to add them to Git.

You need to remove the project directory from the Ignored Files list.

Comment: As ironic as it may be, it didn't solve the issue, however, in a normal scenario I would image it would.

Comment: Please try pressing the "Refresh VCS Changes" button in the Changes view.

Comment: Oh, I see, the files aren't automatically added to the VCS. Thanks for that, you've helped a bunch by just pointing that out.

Comment: No, they won't be automatically added; they will simply be shown as unversioned.